# Rails routing domain wildcard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, subdomain

I'm trying to make a domain wildcard routing for Rails based on [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3). But I'd like to make as nice as "scope" function in native routing, e.g.

```
  domain ':city_id.mysite.com' do
    root :to => "cities#test"
  end
```

IMHO it looks like more prettier than regexps, but I'm too lazy to write the parser for the path like ":city_id.mysite.com" by my own. I belive somewhere inside rails it already exists, but I can't find it in source code.
Also would be great to use :constraints, :as, :scope and other configs for this route, but htis is optionally.

For now my code looks like:

```
module Domain
  class Match
    def initialize(wildcard, *options)
      @wildcard = wildcard
    end

    def matches?(request)
      request.path_parameters[:city_id] = request.subdomain #to replace this with setting parameters from wildcard, :default and so on
      request.subdomain.present? #to replace this string with wildcard-match condition
    end
  end

  module Mapper
    def domain(wildcard='')
      constraints(Domain::Match.new wildcard) { yield }
    end
  end
end

ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper.send(:include, Domain::Mapper)
```

So, I'm able to create routes only for the subdomains

```
  domain 'subdomain' do
    root :to => "cities#test"
  end
```

And I can get only hardcoded parameter 'city_id' in controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, maybe will be usefull for someone. I've found, that Journey::Path::Pattern can be used for this. Adding to intializer:

```
  @pattern = Journey::Path::Pattern.new(
      Journey::Router::Strexp.compile(path, constraints, ['.'])
  )
```

And when checking -

```
  match_data  = @pattern.match(request.host)
  return false if match_data.nil?
```